# AVPlayerViewController issue with iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, ios12

I'm using AVPlayerViewController for playing video it works fine with iOS 11 but the same code doesn't work in iOS 12. could anyone help me to fix this issue please?

```
 let url: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sampleVideo", withExtension: ".mp4")!

    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController?.player = player
    playerController?.view.frame = videoHolderView?.bounds ?? CGRect.zero

    guard let videoView = playerController?.view else { return }
    videoView.tag = 101
    videoHolderView.addSubview(videoView)
    player?.play()
```

Comment: Give us a clue... what does "it doesn't work" mean?, it wont compile? it's building and playing but you getting video and no audio?...

Comment: @Scriptable It compiles but when I tap on the video it just doesn't respond...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue!!!
in iOS 12 if you disable **PlayBackControls** of AVPlayerController, AVPlayer will still consume the tap gesture.

`playerController?.showsPlaybackControls = false`